# Getting and Parsing JSON in the same Activity (Null Pointer Exception)

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception

I want to get and parse json in the same activity but when I try to do this I get

> Null Pointer Exception

I think I am getting this error because background task is slower than my code. 
In My main activity:

```
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        new BackgroundTask().execute();

        categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(this,R.layout.row_layout);//I am sure,there is no problem in Category Adapter
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);

        String id,kategori;

        try {
            Log.d("jsonstring",JSON_STRING); //I am getting error here JSON_STRING causes null pointer.
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            int count = 0;
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");

            while(count<jsonArray.length()){
                JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);

                id = JO.getString("id");
                kategori = JO.getString("kategori");

                Categories categories = new Categories(id,kategori);

                categoryAdapter.add(categories);
                count++;

            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                Categories contact = (Categories) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
               // Log.d("position",""+position);
              //  Log.d("id",""+id);
                Log.d("id",contact.getId());
                Log.d("kategori",contact.getKategori());


            }

        });
```

Background Task class:

```
   class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {


        String json_url= "exampleurl"; // I am sure, here is correct!


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(json_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                while ((json_string  = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){

                    stringBuilder.append(json_string+"\n");

                }

                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();





            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        public BackgroundTask() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           // TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
          //  textView.setText(result);
            JSON_STRING = result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
```

I have Categories class with id and kategori attributes. 
Finally How can I solve this problem? In fact I can parse after getting JSON.

Comment: try moving your parsing related code inside `onPostExecute()`

Comment: Thankss.. I solved my problem.